# How could I convert this goto into a do while loop?

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string choice = string.Empty;
        do
        {
        start:
            int output = 0;
            int number = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Please input a number for it to be counted!");
            bool conversion = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out output);

            if (number < 1000)
            {
                switch (conversion)
                {
                    case true:
                        while (number <= output)
                        {
                            Console.Write(number + " ");
                            number += 2;
                        }
                        break;
                    case false:
                        Console.WriteLine("ERROR: INVALID INPUT!");
                        goto start;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("APPLICATION ERROR: NUMBER MUST BE BELOW OR AT 1000 TO PREVENT OVERFLOW!");
                return;
            }

            do // Here is the beginning of the do code
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n Do you want to continue - Yes or No");
                choice = Console.ReadLine();
                if (choice.ToUpper() != "YES" && choice.ToUpper() != "NO")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ERROR INVALID INPUT: Only input Yes or No!");
                }

            } while (choice.ToUpper() != "YES" && choice.ToUpper() != "NO");
        } while (choice.ToUpper() == "YES");
    }
}
```

I'm using several do while loops in this statement however I'm trumped on how I would put in a loop "ERROR INVALID INPUT:" result when a user puts in anything other than the limits of the assigned integers (i.e. putting decimals or fractions) or if they put a string. I simply used goto because I'm having trouble finding out where to put the do while loop statement. If someone could simply show me how I might replace that one goto with a do while loop then I would be very greatful. (Note if you show me ways I could optimize my code better since I'm still new I probably won't understand it but your welcome to give it your best shot!)

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

The keyword `continue` means to go back to the beginning of the loop. Note that this will recheck the loop condition and break if it is false. Also, most people find do-while loops less readable (and they are really rarely necessary), so try using while loops instead.

There is also the keyword `break` which will simply exit the loop. (not just for switch-case!)

**A more readable version would look something like this:**

```
string userAnswer = "yes";

// while is usually more readable than do-while
while (userAnswer == "yes")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please input a number for it to be counted!");
    int number;

    // Ask for new input until the user inputs a valid number
    while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid number, try again");
    }

    if (number < 1000)
    {
        // Print from 0 to number, jumping in 2's
        for (int i = 0; i <= number; i += 2)
            Console.WriteLine(i + " ");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("APPLICATION ERROR: NUMBER MUST BE BELOW OR AT 1000 TO PREVENT OVERFLOW!");
        continue; // Jump back to the start of this loop
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Continue? (Yes / No)");
    userAnswer = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

    // Ask for new input until the user inputs "Yes" or "No"
    while (userAnswer != "yes" && userAnswer != "no")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid input. Continue? (Yes / No)");
        userAnswer = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I'll post some code that may help and offer some advice. Basically declare a bool named 'loopCompleted' which will continue the do while loop until you set it to true. The downside is that it will not instantly exit the loop like return/goto/etc but this is not a problem in most cases.

You may want to use if/else instead of switch(conversion), its sort of interesting to see it done that way but its a bit over the top :)

If Int.TryParse() doesnt already return false for fractional values (e.g. [15.08] returns [true] with [15] ). Then you can store Console.ReadLine() before using TryParse, then use stringName.Contains() to check for the '.' Basically, if the conversion succeeds you also check if it contained the decimal point.

Another way to check is to do float.TryParse() then check if it is a fractional value.

```
bool fraction = false;
if( number % 1.0f > 0)
    fraction == true;
```

% is called modulus, it returns the remainder of A / B
If a number has a remainder when divided by 1 it must be a fractional value.

```
    //start:
    bool loopCompleted = false;
    do
    {
        int output = 0;
        int number = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Please input a number for it to be counted!");
        bool conversion = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out output);

        if (conversion && number < 1000)
        {
            while (number <= output)
            {
                 Console.Write(number + " ");
                 number += 2;
            }
            loopCompleted = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if(conversion == false)
            {
                 Console.WriteLine("ERROR: INVALID INPUT!");
            }
            else
            {
                 Console.WriteLine("APPLICATION ERROR: NUMBER MUST BE BELOW OR AT 1000 TO PREVENT OVERFLOW!");
            }
        }
   } while(!loopCompleted)
```